# BigCommerce theme preview

Tags: themes, preview, bigcommerce

I'm customizing a BigCommerce theme. I can modify the theme files using the online editor, but changes are immediately reflected on the live site. It is obviously bad practice to edit and test live. What is the common-practice way to preview theme changes before publishing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method built in to Bigcommerce to preview site changes. However, there are a variety of ways that you can test changes you want to make to your store.

First, you can create an alternate product, category or content page template together with test data to try out changes.

Second, you can apply CSS changes locally only using the Web Developer Toolbar's "Add User Style Sheet" feature in Firefox. This way you can see the impact of style changes without putting them live.

Third, if testing smaller structural changes, wrap your new section(s) with a div with `style="display:none;"` applied. Then, open the developer tools in your browser and remove the display none to test.

Lastly, if you are on a high traffic Bigcommmerce store and/or these methods are not adequate for your needs, you can always clone your store into a development environment and test your changes there first.